# How to assign a probability to each label in a Scikit Learn SVM during training?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

When training and testing a SVM implemented in Scikit Learn, how can I assign a previously known probability to each label in the dataset? Basically there are examples I am 100% sure of, and other which have lower probabilities.

Comment: Make sure to understand the basics of SVMs, Classification and Regression. Then you can reason about approximations to your use-case using sample_weights or multi-output regression.

Comment: I hope to have understood the basics of SVM's, and there is an implementation for it in [LIBSVM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21659/train-a-svm-based-classifier-while-taking-into-account-the-weight-information). I just would like to know if is possible to do this also with Scikit Learn.

Comment: If you did unterstand their approach (compare with my comment), you should be able to find the functionality in sklearn. Beware: this approach is basically the opposite of your *I do not have examples which I wish to favor, all are equally important.*

Answer (score -1):

Probabilities don't really come into it. But for examples you wish to favor, you could add `k` additional copies of them to the training data.

Comment: I don't understand why probabilities do not come into it. I do not have examples which I wish to favor, all are equally important. The labels of some data examples are just not so sure as others.